# Stackoverflow when splitting string using regex

Tags: java, regex, mapreduce, stack-overflow

I'm doing a project in MapReduce using Amazon Web Services and I'm having this error:

> FATAL [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Error running child :
>   java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4658)

I read a few other questions to understand why this happened and it seems my regex has repetitive alternative paths. This is the regex:

```
\\s+(?=(?:(?<=[a-zA-Z])\"(?=[A-Za-z])|\"[^\"]*\"|[^\"])*$)
```

What it does is that it splits by space except when they are inside these symbols `< >` or these `" "`. So basically takes strings that are inside those 2 types of symbol. I have tried many other versions but none works, so I am far away from an optimal one. I am kind of lost and it's the first time Im using these complicated regexs. Can someone please give a better option for my regex?

I would truly appreciate every feedback regarding this!

EDIT:
This string with URLs inside <> and text inside "" and spaces:
<\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user&sioc_id=1/> "HEY" <.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>

should produce these 3 Strings:
1. <\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user&sioc_id=1/> (with or without <>)
2. "HEY"
3. <.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>

EDIT 2:
I think the symbols <> are confusing. I am trying to find a regex that splits by one or more spaces without taking into consideration the spaces inside " ", since the urls do not have spaces.

Comment: you need to provide some formatted input and expected output respectively. That way it would be better understandable and alternative solution might be provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
\s+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fn1IoR/2/)

```
    String string = "abc d<\\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user &sioc_id=1/> \"HEY 1\" 2 3 <.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/> \"tra la\" <asdfadsf sadfasdf/> 4    \"sdf sdf\" 5 6";
    String[] res=string.split("\\s+(?=(?:(?:[^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

Will output:

```
[abc, d<\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user, &sioc_id=1/>, "HEY 1", 2, 3, <.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>, "tra la", <asdfadsf, sadfasdf/>, 4, "sdf sdf", 5, 6]
```

Comment: This is not working in my example although the approach is what Im searching. In my output Im having spaces  and <URL> "String" is not divided. Said more simply, I need a regex that splits **by space** except for spaces inside " ".

Comment: Updated regex is not ignoring spaces inside " ". The strings are being divided word by word.  @RizwanM.Tuman

Comment: @Angie94 I wish your requirement would have much clearer in the first place, plz try now.. and let me know is that what you have wanted

Comment: @Ritzwan M.Tuman I apologize, but however I realized it while trying myself. I accepted your answer. It works both in local and in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `split()`. Use a `find()` loop instead, with this regex:

```
(?:<[^<]*>
   |
   "[^"]*"
   |
   \S
   )+
```

Example:

```
String input = "<\\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user&sioc_id=1/> \"HEY\" <.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:<[^<]*>|\"[^\"]*\"|\\S)+");
for (Matcher m = p.matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

*Output*

```
<\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user&sioc_id=1/>
"HEY"
<.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>
```

Comment: This works very well, but I want to use split() for certain reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to match: tags OR what's between the double quotes OR the remaining non-whitespaces.

```
<[^>]+>|"[^"]+"|\S+
```

For example:

```
String str = "<\\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user&sioc_id=1/> \"HEY\" YOU! \"How Are You?\" <.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>";

final java.util.regex.Pattern pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("<[^>]+>|\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+");
java.util.regex.Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("match: " + matcher.group(0));
}
```

Prints:

```
match: <\janhaeussler.com/?sioc_type=user&sioc_id=1/>
match: "HEY"
match: YOU!
match: "How Are You?"
match: <.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type/>
```